# Filter/find and something else in JS for search object's in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have some JSON structure. An example with the first item[0] object is shown below.

```
{
    "item": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "name": "attachments",
            "description": {
                "content": "",
                "type": "text/plain"
            },
            "item": [
                {
                    "id": "",
                    "name": "Get all attachments.",
                    "request": {
                        "name": "Get all attachments.",
                        "description": {
                            "content": "This method allows to retrieve attachments.\n",
                            "type": "text/plain"
                        },
                        "url": {
                            "path": [
                                "attachment"
                            ],
                            "host": [
                                "{{baseUrl}}"
                            ],
                            "query": [
                                {
                                    "disabled": false,
                                    "description": {
                                        "content": "A number of entities in result set.",
                                        "type": "text/plain"
                                    },
                                    "key": "limit",
                                    "value": "10"
                                },
                                {
                                    "disabled": false,
                                    "description": {
                                        "content": "How many entities should be skipped.",
                                        "type": "text/plain"
                                    },
                                    "key": "offset",
                                    "value": "0"
                                }
                            ],
                            "variable": []
                        },
                        "header": [
                            {
                                "key": "Accept",
                                "value": "application/json"
                            }
                        ],
                        "method": "GET"
                    },
                    "response": [
                        {
                            "_": {
                                "postman_previewlanguage": "json"
                            },
                            "id": "",
                            "name": "A list of all attachments.",
                            "originalRequest": {
                                "url": {
                                    "path": [
                                        "attachment"
                                    ],
                                    "host": [
                                        "{{baseUrl}}"
                                    ],
                                    "query": [
                                        {
                                            "key": "limit",
                                            "value": "10"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "key": "offset",
                                            "value": "0"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "variable": []
                                },
                                "header": [
                                    {
                                        "description": {
                                            "content": "Added as a part of security scheme: apikey",
                                            "type": "text/plain"
                                        },
                                        "key": "Token",
                                        "value": "<API Key>"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "method": "GET",
                                "body": {}
                            },
                            "status": "OK",
                            "code": 200,
                            "header": [
                                {
                                    "key": "Content-Type",
                                    "value": "application/json"
                                }
                            ],
                            "body": "",
                            "cookie": []
                        }
                    ],
                    "event": [
                        {
                            "listen": "test",
                            "script": {
                                "id": "",
                                "type": "text/javascript",
                                "exec": []
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "event": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm doing some transformations with this JSON, the snippet on the ts is listed below.

```
// @ts-ignore
const { promisify } = require('util');
// @ts-ignore
const fs = require('fs');
const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);
const writeFile = promisify(fs.writeFile);
const path = './api.json';

// @ts-ignore
(async () => {
  try {
    const contents = await readFile(path);
    const jsonContent = JSON.parse(contents);

//...

    jsonContent.item[0].item[0].event[0].script.exec = [
      'something',
      ...jsonContent.item[0].item[0].event[0].script.exec,
    ];

//...

    await writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(jsonContent));
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
})();
```

I need to make edits to my JSON file. I'm accessing the hard order in the nested JSON structure and it makes it hard to set the bulletproof status for my script, because it doesn't guarantee the correct order every time I generate a JSON file. How can I refer to the right object and array through unambiguous output in search?

Comment: The only actual [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) in your question and script is the content of `api,json` and the content of `contents`. `jsonContent` is not [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) (and has therefor a misleading name)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let oldArray = jsonContent.item[0].item[0].event[0].script.exec.slice();
jsonContent.item[0].item[0].event[0].script.exec = [
      'something',
      ...oldArray,
    ];
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, let me clarify a little bit. My code, in the example works, but what if the order of output changes? In the example I rely on a rigid order, and if the order changes? Then my code won't work. Can I somehow find the desired object by search and change it already (not as in the example is implemented)?

Comment: @1ivliev I am sorry I don't understand how the order can affect it.